# How to remove codehaus.org dependency when building Mule Connector

Tags: maven, mule

I am trying to build a Mule Connector, everything has been done but when i am trying to build the connector into jar file with the below command:

```
mvn package -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false
```

then there is error return saying that the connection to codehaus.org (which is somehow shutdown) is not available.

Comment: Would you give us more details, links to projects, some source code ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the mirror.
To configure a mirror of a given repository, you provide it in your settings file settings.xml, giving the new repository its own id and url, and specify the mirrorOf setting that is the ID of the repository you are using a mirror of.

```
            <mirror>
              <id>Codehaus id</id>
              <mirrorOf>codehaus.org</mirrorOf>
              <name>Codehaus.org repo</name>
              <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/</url>
            </mirror>
```

This should solve your problem